# LVM: Shrinking /scratch, extending SWAP

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

```
kamals@poc02:~$ sudo lvs
  LV                     VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root                   vg_system -wi-ao----  63.98g
  scratch                vg_system -wi-ao---- 465.66g
  .
  .
  swap                   vg_system -wi-ao----  16.00g
  var                    vg_system -wi-ao----  31.99g
kamals@poc02:~$ sudo vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  vg_system   1   6   0 wz--n- 930.51g 296.88g
kamals@poc02:~$ df -h /scratch/
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_system-scratch  459G  726M  435G   1% /scratch
kamals@poc02:~$ sudo umount /scratch

kamals@poc02:~$ sudo e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/vg_system-scratch
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
scratch: 25/30523392 files (16.0% non-contiguous), 2134330/122070016 blocks
kamals@poc02:~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_system-scratch 450G
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/mapper/vg_system-scratch to 117964800 (4k) blocks.
The filesystem on /dev/mapper/vg_system-scratch is now 117964800 (4k) blocks long.
kamals@poc02:~$ sudo lvreduce -L -9G /dev/mapper/vg_system-scratch
  WARNING: Reducing active logical volume to 456.66 GiB
  THIS MAY DESTROY YOUR DATA (filesystem etc.)
Do you really want to reduce scratch? [y/n]: y
  Size of logical volume vg_system/scratch changed from 465.66 GiB (119209 extents) to 456.66 GiB (116905 extents).
  Logical volume scratch successfully resized.
kamals@poc02:~$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/vg_system-scratch /scratch/
kamals@poc02:~$ lsblk | grep scratch
  ├─vg_system-scratch                252:4    0 456.7G  0 lvm  /scratch
kamals@poc02:~$
kamals@poc02:~$ df -h /scratch/
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_system-scratch  443G  727M  420G   1% /scratch
kamals@poc02:~$


SWAP Space extend:
===================

kamals@poc02:~$ lsblk | grep swap
  ├─vg_system-swap                   252:1    0    16G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
kamals@poc02:~$ sudo swapoff /dev/vg_system/swap
kamals@poc02:~$
kamals@poc02:~$ sudo lvresize -L+9G /dev/vg_system/swap
  Size of logical volume vg_system/swap changed from 16.00 GiB (4095 extents) to 25.00 GiB (6399 extents).
  Logical volume swap successfully resized.
kamals@poc02:~$ sudo mkswap /dev/vg_system/swap
mkswap: /dev/vg_system/swap: warning: wiping old swap signature.
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 25 GiB (26839347200 bytes)
no label, UUID=5fbefbfc-b0fc-46d5-8d5e-b547c184ac14
kamals@poc02:~$ sudo swapon /dev/vg_system/swap
kamals@poc02:~$
kamals@poc02:~$ free -th | grep -i swap
Swap:           24G          0B         24G
kamals@poc02:~$
kamals@poc02:~$ lsblk | grep swap
  ├─vg_system-swap                   252:1    0    25G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

Here I am trying to shrink the `/scratch` data disk by `9G` and increase that amount to `SWAP` space.

I am seeing here the LVM reduce of `/scratch` is working as expected `(465.66G-9G ~= 456.7G)`, but why the FS size in `df -h` is `443G` from `459G` just by reducing `9G`.

I performed once again with reducing `1G`, I am seeing df value reducing to `428G`.

```
kamals@poc02:~$ df -h /scratch/
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_system-scratch  428G  727M  405G   1% /scratch
kamals@poc02:~$
```

I have couple of questions,

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Is these steps are correct? Can I implement them in production servers just by taking downtime ?

Is there any chance of data loss with these steps ?

Is there any better solution ?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used 450G for the filesystem size:

> ```
> $ sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_system-scratch 450G
> ```

But your LV is larger than that (456.66G):

> ```
> $ sudo lvreduce -L -9G /dev/mapper/vg_system-scratch
> WARNING: Reducing active logical volume to 456.66 GiB
> THIS MAY DESTROY YOUR DATA (filesystem etc.)
> ```

So you can either reduce the LV even further (to 450G) or grow the filesystem to the actual LV size with another call to `resize2fs`. Otherwise 6.66G remain unused.

Actually `lvreduce` has the `--resizefs` option to handle the filesystem resize for you.

Even if you do it manually, there is no actual need to make the filesystem smaller than the LV size. If you use 450G for the filesystem you can use 450G for the LV, too. It helps to use round numbers instead of fractions, though. If you actually want it to be 456.66GiB, it might be better to express that in MiB instead.

Regarding other missing space, check `tune2fs -l` for this filesystem if it has a root reserve (`Reserved block count` != 0) and if so, change it with `tune2fs -m`. That's if you don't need/want a root reserve for this filesystem.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. But problem is, even if I try to reduce to 450G, why FS reduced to 443G.

```
/dev/mapper/vg_system-scratch  443G  727M  420G   1% /scratch

```

Comment: Can you please post the correct way of doing this, so I can test it in a test machine and move to production servers. There shouldn't be zero tolerance of mistakes, data loss. Thanks

Comment: By this way, is there any chance of data loss from scratch disk ? 
Have to do in 4 production servers.

Answer (score 0):

Tried `lvreduce` with `--resizefs`, recovered 17G.

```
kamals@poc02:~$ sudo lvs
scratch                vg_system -wi-ao---- 454.66g

kamals@poc02:~$ df -h /scratch/
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_system-scratch  428G  727M  405G   1% /scratch
kamals@poc02:~$ sudo e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/vg_system-scratch
.
.
scratch: 25/28442624 files (16.0% non-contiguous), 2003774/113770496 blocks

kamals@poc02:~$ sudo lvreduce --resizefs -L -3G /dev/mapper/vg_system-scratch
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
scratch: clean, 25/28442624 files, 2003774/113770496 blocks
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/mapper/vg_system-scratch to 118400000 (4k) blocks.
The filesystem on /dev/mapper/vg_system-scratch is now 118400000 (4k) blocks long.

  Size of logical volume vg_system/scratch changed from 454.66 GiB (116393 extents) to 451.66 GiB (115625 extents).
  Logical volume scratch successfully resized.

kamals@poc02:~$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/vg_system-scratch /scratch/
kamals@poc02:~$ df -h /scratch/
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_system-scratch  445G  727M  422G   1% /scratch
kamals@poc02:~$

kamals@poc02:~$ sudo lvs
  scratch                vg_system -wi-ao---- 451.66g
```